# Finding limit of a sequence in a metric space.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

Another problem from an assignment I'm having some trouble making a start on.

> Consider the sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in the metric space $\left(\mathbb{R}^3, d_3\right)$, with $d_3(x, y) = \|x−y\|_2$, and state their limit if one exists.
>
> i.) $x_n = (1-\frac{1}{n}, 2, \frac{n}{n^2+1})$*

There's more parts to this question but I would just like to know how to do this for one then I'll finish it for myself.

I've been trying to look at it in terms of conventional limits but I'm thrown by the metric space aspect. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: The metric you have written down is just the usual Euclidean distance. Given that can you now solve this problem? Or did you mean $\| x - y \|_3$?

Comment: remind me what $||x - y||_2$ means?  The euclidean distance of the square root of the sum of the squares?

Comment: Fancy language  aside, we are asking whether a certain explicit sequence converges. It seems clear that it converges to $v=(1,2,0)$. One may be expected to then give an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof of convergence, so we will need to compute the distance between $x_n$ and $v$, and show that it can be made $\lt \epsilon$ by choosing $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that (1,2,0) may be a limit.
$||x_n-(1,2,0)||=||(-1/n,0,\frac{n}{n^2+1})||=\sqrt{(-\frac{1}{n})^2+(\frac{n}{n^2+1})^2 }$ and evalute the limit in $\mathbb{R}$, it is 0.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
You are just in a 3D space, where each coordinate is really an independent subsequence. The sequence converges iff it converges for each of the coordinates.